# In a MySQL database how can you tell the storage size of each column?

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database how can you tell the storage size that each column of a table is taking up?  Relevant for variable length columns like TextField.

Comment: Do you have access to the mySql db init file used to create it in the frist place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To character data field, would be:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(`column`)) FROM `Table`
```

If you are using some numerical data type, you could just get a count on the rows, and multiply it by the size, for instance 4 for INTEGER, or 8 for DOUBLE, but It won't reflect the actual size taken up on disk however.

You can get the size of an entire table with:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE `Table`;
```

Comment: +1 with the caveat that the size in `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is only a rough estimate, and it can be inaccurate by a surprisingly high margin, e.g. 10-20%